# Are there updated notebooks for Gray's Modern Differential Geometry of CURVES and SURFACES with Mathematica?

Tags: notebooks, upgrade

The most recent notebook I have found for **Modern Differential Geometry of
CURVES and SURFACES with Mathematica** by Alfred Gray, Elsa Abbena, Simon Salamon are here:

http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/abbena/gray/

They do not work properly under 10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).  Some of it is not too hard to fix.  But some of the problems are arcane.  For example, after fixing the argument list for *Arrow[]* , and putting "Section" in quotes in *Figure 1.1*, I get

`Syntax::sntxf: 
   "" cannot be followed by 
    "{0,0}, \[Gamma][\[Pi]/6]}]}".`

If I copy the code into a new notebook, it works.  Not only that, the error message differed if I revert to the original notebook, and make the exact same changes to the code.  There are several notebooks, and I would rather not debug each by hand.

Any ideas where I might find updated notebooks, or some way to update the existing notebooks programmatically?

---

Edit to add:  I'm finding that a combination of sledge hammer and duck tape has rendered a couple of the notebooks usable.

That is:

- Revert the Stylesheet to default.
- Select the largest possible cell group and set "Format"->"Word wrapping"->"Wrap at Window Width".
- Copy the Mathematica input code from the existing cells to new Input cells.
- Remove "$<<$Graphics`Arrow`".
- Wrap all the argument lists in existing Arrow[]s in $\left\{\right\}$.
- Remove ";"'s (semicolons) from the ends of code that is intended to display graphics.
- Remove/replace legacy commands.
- Manually re-enter code that still refuses to cooperate.
- Copy code to a "scratch" Notebook for testing.
- Frequently restart the kernel.
- Occasionally utter profanity.

It would really be nice to see this code updated so that a novice with Mathematica could use it to learn both differential geometry and Mathematica using Gray's wonderful book.  I will suggest focusing on function over form, when it comes to the use of Stylesheets.

Comment: I have the same question. Have you had any luck?

Comment: Sorry.  No progress. Grey's book is still a masterpiece waiting to be realized.  I've only gotten through a fraction of it, and have benifitted greatly from the effort.  It is still on my list of books that must be read.